# Permanently deleting a git tag in a multi-user project

Tags: git, github, tags

One of our team on a project with many people working on it created a tag with the same name as a working branch. This has been causing problems with many people's operations with this branch (with their various git clients).

I tried to visit everyone and do the same as `git tag -d badtag` as well as `git push origin :refs/tags/badtag`. But people always get missed, and eventually someone comes along and re-pushes the tag.

Is there anything we can do? It's driving us nuts. We use github as our main repository.